# Общий стек для int и char

Tags: c++

Делаю форт-компилятор на *С++*, столкнулся с проблемой реализации общего для `int` и `char[]` стека. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать общий стек?

Comment: Под char[] вы понимаете строки переменной длины? 

Ну, никто вам не помешает хранить в стеке еще и длину того, что вы туда затолкали, хоть это и будет накладно.

Comment: Хм. А вы уверены, что если возникают такие вопросы, вам уже стоит писать компилятор?

Comment: По теме вопроса: оберните в структуру, в которой указан тип данных. Храните в стеке указатель на эту структуру. Или воспользуйтесь `boost::any`.

Comment: Вопросы возникают, т.к. учусь. Попробую boost::any, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @j0hn: Если вы только учитесь, вам не стоит начинать с компилятора. Попробуйте что-то более простое концептуально.

Comment: Форт и есть самое простое концептуально

Answer (score 3):

Есть минимум два варианта:

1. Си-подход:

   ```
   typedef struct ForthType {
       enum { INT; FLOAT; PTR; STR; BYTECODE; ... } type; // тэг типа
       union { // значение, в памяти перекрываются в одних адресах
           int i;
           float f;
           void *p;
           char *s;
           ...
       }
   } D[Dsz]; int Dp=0;

   #define PUSH(X) { D[Dp++]=X; }

   #define POP(X) (D[--Dp])
   ```
2. С++ : обобщая задачу -- требуется **гетерогенный контейнер** способный хранить произвольные типы данных (например список в Python или Lisp). Реализуется через

   1. **дерево типов, наследованное от одного `полиморфного` базового класса**
   2. **любые STLные контейнеры хранят указатели на базовый класс `Base*`**
   3. всю работу с объектами нужно реализовывать через `Base*`, определение конкретного типа `typeid(Base*number)` и `dymanic_cast<Int*>(number)->...`

```
struct Base {
   virtual ~Base();      // для базового класса необходима
                            // 1+ виртуальная функция
                            // по классике: [пустой] виртуальный деструктор
   virtual string dot();    // для каждого типа объектов нужна
                            // своя реализация слова <точка>
   string val;              // строка -- универсальный формат данных:
                            // любые данные можно представить в текстовом виде,
                            // в частности имена слов
   vector<Base*> bytecode;  // понадобится когда начнем реализовывать
                            // определения слов
   virtual add(Base*);      // функции базовой арифметики
   virtual sub(Base*);
   virtual mul(Base*);
   virtual div(Base*);
   ...
};
```

Стек данных:

```
stack<Base*> DataStack; // (!!!) храним не объекты, а указатели на них
```

Стек возвратов:

```
stack<Base*> ReturnStack;
```

Словари

```
struct Vocabulary:Base;
Vocabulary FORTH("FORTH",NULL);

struct Vocabulary:Base {
    Vocabulary(string name,Vocabulary*next=&FORTH);
    Vocabulary* next;         // для реализации дерева словарей для поиска
    map<string,Base*> words;  // хранилище определений
    Base* Find(string);       // функция рекурсивного поиска words/*next
};

Vocabulary FORTH;
```

Наследуем типы с которыми мы хотим работать:

Целые (только числа, **не** адреса):

```
struct Int: Base { 
    int val; // (!) оборачиваем нужный тип
    Int(std::string); Int(int); string dot(); // конструкторы и дамп
    int add(Base*); int sub(Base*); 
    ... 
}; // вычисления
```

В свое время жутко не хватало плавающей точки, причем слов кодирования/декодирования float/str (1), даже пришлось на intXXh вешать резидентный калькулятор написанный на TurboC (1) для вычислений элементарно было использовать стек FPU)

```
struct Float: Base { 
    float val ; // (!) оборачиваем нужный тип
    Float(string); Float(float); string dot(); 
    ... 
};
```

Указатели

```
struct Ptr: Base { Ptr(void*); void *val; };
```